# Setting an Xcode plist property

Tags: xcode, macos, config, puppet, boxen

I recently started using [boxen](https://github.com/boxen) to configure my Mac and would love to configure particular XCode settings using this approach.

I found the following `plist` file: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist` and when I try to use PListBuddy to edit the file, it appears to temporarily work, but it eventually automatically resets itself.

Given this command to set a value:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set DVTTextShowLineNumbers true" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
```

If I immediately run this to read the value.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print DVTTextShowLineNumbers" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
```

It prints `true`, but if I open XCode, and/or I wait a moment and re-run the print command it eventually starts printing `false`.

If I open the plist file `open ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist` and run the above commands, I can actually see the plist viewer refresh toggling between my set value of `YES` and then automatically being reverted to `NO`

Anyone have any thoughts on what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Just learned about [defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html)

I can change the value by running the following command

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTTextShowLineNumbers YES
```